# Add data-action to all img that contain a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using this plugin: https://github.com/fat/zoom.js/

I'd like to select all `img` that have the class `img-responsive` and add `data-action="zoom"` to the element. Is this possible using jQuery? Is the performance going to be really poor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`jQuery.data( key, value )`**](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method

```
$('img.img-responsive').data('action','zoom');
```

Or using [**`jQuery.attr( attributeName, value )`,**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$('img.img-responsive').attr('data-action','zoom');
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize `.attr` would add to the element.

Comment: @evan – That is why `.attr` exists, to manipulate `attributes` ;) I'm glad it helped..

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
$('img[class="img-responsive"]').attr('data-action', 'zoom');
```

Perfomance should be good :)